Right-side canvas scrolls, even when mouse is on the Left-side canvas
I've been trying to make a program, with 3 layouts depending on the window's width (using Tkinter).
The issue is in the medium layout. Whenever I place my mouse onto the left canvas and use the MouseWheel, the right canvas scrolls, when the left canvas is supposed to. When my mouse is placed on the right canvas and I use the mouse wheel, the right canvas scrolls. I can't find any solution to this.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random as rand

class App(tk.Tk):
    def init(self, Geometry, Icon, MinimumSizesDictionary):
        super().init() 

        self.title("Practise")
        self.geometry(f"{Geometry[0]}x{Geometry[1]}")
        self.minsize(Geometry[0], Geometry[1])
        self.iconbitmap(Icon)
    
        # variables
    
        self.MinimumSizesDictionary = MinimumSizesDictionary
    
        # widgets
    
        self.LayoutNSizeChecker = LayoutNSizeChecker(self, self.MinimumSizesDictionary)
    
        # run
        self.mainloop()

class LayoutNSizeChecker(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, Parent, MinimumSizesDictionary):
        super ().__init__(Parent)

        self.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")
        self.MinimumSizesDictionary = MinimumSizesDictionary
        self.MinimumSize = self.CurrentMinimumSize = None
        self.Layout = None
    
        # binding an event to the main frame
        self.bind("<Configure>", lambda event : self.Update())
    
        # binding an event to the window
        Parent.bind("<Configure>", lambda event : self.CheckScreenSize(event, Parent))
    
    def CheckScreenSize(self, event, Window):
        if event.widget == Window:
    
            for Key, Value in self.MinimumSizesDictionary.items():
                self.Delta = event.width - Key
    
                if self.Delta >= 0: self.MinimumSize = Key
    
            if self.CurrentMinimumSize != self.MinimumSize:
                self.CurrentMinimumSize = self.MinimumSize
    
                if self.CurrentMinimumSize == 300:
                    for Widget in self.winfo_children():
                        Widget.destroy()
                        self.Destroyed = True
    
                    print("small layout")
                    self.Layout = "Small"
    
                    # variables
    
                    self.NumberOfButtons = 20
                    self.SpaceEachRowTakes = 100
                    self.TotalHeight = self.NumberOfButtons * self.SpaceEachRowTakes
    
                    # canvas
                    self.Canvas = tk.Canvas(self, scrollregion = (0, 0, self.winfo_width(), self.TotalHeight))
                    self.Canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")
    
                    # canvas frame
                    self.CanvasFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
    
                    # scroll bar
                    self.ScrollBar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient = "vertical", command = self.Canvas.yview)
                    self.ScrollBar.place(relx = 1, rely = 0, relheight = 1, anchor = "ne")
                    self.Canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.ScrollBar.set)
    
                    # scroll using the mousewheel
                    self.Canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda event : self.Scroll(event))
    
                    for i in range(1, 21):
                        self.FramePortion = ttk.Frame(self.CanvasFrame)
    
                        # variables
    
                        self.TextData = ["hello!", "goodbye!", "cya", "innit", "lol", "xd", "alr", "bro", "dude", "wsg"]
    
                        # making the grid
    
                        self.FramePortion.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform = "z")
                        self.FramePortion.columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight = 1, uniform = "z")
    
                        # the widgets
                                    
                        self.Button1 = ttk.Button(self.FramePortion, text = i)
                        self.Button2 = ttk.Button(self.FramePortion, text = rand.choice(self.TextData))
                        self.Button3 = ttk.Button(self.FramePortion, text = rand.choice(self.TextData))
    
                        # placing the widgets onto the grid we created earlier
    
                        self.Button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nesw", padx = 5, pady = 5)
                        self.Button2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nesw", padx = 5, pady = 5)
                        self.Button3.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "nesw", padx = 5, pady = 5)
                        self.FramePortion.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")
                        self.Destroyed = False
                        
                elif self.CurrentMinimumSize == 600:
                    print("medium layout")
                    self.Layout = "Medium"
    
                    for Widget in self.winfo_children():
                        Widget.destroy()
                        self.Destroyed = True
    
                    # grid for main frame
    
                    self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform = "z")
                    self.columnconfigure((0, 2), weight = 6, uniform = "z")
                    self.columnconfigure((1, 3), weight = 1, uniform = "z")
    
                    # left side layout
                    self.LeftFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
                    self.LeftFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nesw")
                    self.LeftCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.LeftFrame, scrollregion = (0, 0, self.LeftFrame.winfo_width(), self.TotalHeight / 2))
                    self.LeftCanvas.pack(side = "left", pady = 10, expand = True, fill = "both")
    
                    self.LeftCanvasFrame = ttk.Frame(self.LeftCanvas)
    
                    # scroll bar
                    self.LeftScrollBar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient = "vertical", command = self.LeftCanvas.yview)
                    self.LeftScrollBar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "ns")
                    self.LeftCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.LeftScrollBar.set)
    
                    # scroll using the mouse wheel
                    self.LeftCanvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda event : self.LeftScroll(event))

# 

                    for i in range(1, 11):
                        self.LeftFramePortion = ttk.Frame(self.LeftCanvasFrame)
                        self.Button4 = ttk.Button(self.LeftFramePortion, text = i)
                        self.Button5 = ttk.Button(self.LeftFramePortion, text = rand.choice(self.TextData))
                        self.Button6 = ttk.Button(self.LeftFramePortion, text = rand.choice(self.TextData))
                        self.Button4.pack(expand = True, fill = "both", padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
                        self.Button5.pack(expand = True, fill = "both", padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
                        self.Button6.pack(expand = True, fill = "both", padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
                        self.LeftFramePortion.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")
    
                    # right side layout
                    self.RightFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
                    self.RightFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "nesw")
                    self.RightCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.RightFrame, scrollregion=(0, 0, self.RightFrame.winfo_width(), self.TotalHeight / 2))
                    self.RightCanvas.pack(side = "left", pady = 10, expand = True, fill = "both")
    
                    self.RightCanvasFrame = ttk.Frame(self.RightCanvas)
    
                    # scroll bar
                    self.RightScrollBar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient = "vertical", command = self.RightCanvas.yview)
                    self.RightScrollBar.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = "ns")
                    self.RightCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.RightScrollBar.set)
    
                    # scroll using the mouse wheel
                    self.RightCanvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda event : self.RightScroll(event))
                    for i in range(11, 21):
                        self.RightFramePortion = ttk.Frame(self.RightCanvasFrame)
                        self.Button7 = ttk.Button(self.RightFramePortion, text = i)
                        self.Button8 = ttk.Button(self.RightFramePortion, text = rand.choice(self.TextData))
                        self.Button9 = ttk.Button(self.RightFramePortion, text = rand.choice(self.TextData))
                        self.Button7.pack(expand = True, fill = "both", padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
                        self.Button8.pack(expand = True, fill = "both", padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
                        self.Button9.pack(expand = True, fill = "both", padx = 2.5, pady = 2.5)
                        self.RightFramePortion.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")
    
                    self.Destroyed = False
    
                elif self.CurrentMinimumSize == 1000:
                    print("large layout")
                    self.Layout = "Large"
    
                    for Widget in self.winfo_children():
                        Widget.destroy()
                        self.Destroyed = True
    
    def Update(self):
        if not self.Destroyed and self.Layout == "Small":
            self.Canvas.create_window(
                (0, 0),
                anchor = "nw",
                window = self.CanvasFrame,
                width = self.winfo_width(),
                height = self.TotalHeight
            )
    
        elif not self.Destroyed and self.Layout == "Medium":
            self.LeftCanvas.create_window(
                (0, 0),
                anchor = "nw",
                window = self.LeftCanvasFrame,
                width = self.LeftFrame.winfo_width(),
                height = self.TotalHeight / 2
            )
    
            self.RightCanvas.create_window(
                (0, 0),
                anchor = "nw",
                window = self.RightCanvasFrame,
                width = self.RightFrame.winfo_width(),
                height = self.TotalHeight / 2
            )
    
    def Scroll(self, event):
        if not self.Destroyed and self.Layout == "Small":
            self.Canvas.yview_scroll(-int(event.delta / 60), "units")
    
    def LeftScroll(self, event): # left scroll bar function for medium layout
        self.LeftCanvas.yview_scroll(-int(event.delta / 60), "units")
    
    def RightScroll(self, event): # right scroll bar function for medium layout
        self.RightCanvas.yview_scroll(-int(event.delta / 60), "units")

App = App([300, 300], "icon.ico", {300 : "Small", 600 : "Medium", 1000 : "Large"})

as always in the medium layout, whenever i use the mouse wheel, it scrolls the right canvas no matter what.

line 220, in 
App = App([300, 300], "icon.ico", {300 : "Small", 600 : "Medium", 1000 : "Large"})  TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not list

It is because you have use bind_all() for the event <MouseWheel> on both canvases, so the last binding will override the former one.
You can bind_all() to a common callback and find the corresponding canvas widget to be scrolled:
...
self.LeftCanvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.scroll_canvas) # bind to common callback
...
self.RightCanvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.scroll_canvas) # bind to common callback
...

And the common callback:
def scroll_canvas(self, event):
    # find the canvas widget
    widget = event.widget
    root = widget.winfo_toplevel()
    while widget != root and not isinstance(widget, tk.Canvas):
        widget = widget.master
    # if it is a canvas widget, do the scrolling
    if isinstance(widget, tk.Canvas):
        widget.yview_scroll(-event.delta//60, 'units')

